# Difference in URLs to access the Controller Mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn `Spring Framework` and while going through the `Spring MVC` and `Spring Boot REST` to create a dummy project, I noticed below difference in the way the `Tomcat` responds to your `URL` in the browser

**Spring Boot**

http://localhost:8080/

```
Redirects to the Controller that is mapped to "/"
```

http://localhost:8080/springbootrestapp

```
where "springbootrestapp" is the project name, it gives HTTP 404 resource not found error
```

**Spring MVC**

http://localhost:8080/

```
Opens the Tomcat Home page
```

http://localhost:8080/springmvc

```
where "springmvc" is the project name, it redirects to the Controller that is mapped to "/"
```

My doubt is why in case of `Spring Boot` just entering the `localhost:8080` redirects to the `controller` mapped to `"/"` whereas in case of `Spring MVC`(without Spring Boot configurations) it needs `http://localhost:8080/<projectname>/` to redirect to `controller` mapped to `"/"` ?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is very basic: we just have to delete the `/ROOT/` folder in **`$CATALINA_HOME\webapps`**, rename our **`springbootrestapp.war` (or `springmvc.war`) to `ROOT.war`, and deploy it.**

Our app will now be available at *http://localhost:8080/.*

There are different solutions not to change the filename. [You can review the recommendations here.](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue In my case before running my Spring-MVC application I started the tomcat server I didn't stop so whenever I access localhost:8080/ it redirect me to Tomcat Client.